VS Code on Linux disappears suddenly - which logs can tell me reasons for this?
I am running VS Code on a Linux displaying on a separate X11 server. VS Code occasionally just "disappears" (including its processes).
I assume this unexpected application shutdowns are to do with the unstable X11 connection. However  I would like trouble shoot this viaVS Code's logs. Under ~/.config/Code/logs I see lots of logs some under subdirectories like window1. Which log records these type of application shutdowns?
